# How do I calc a total row using a PIVOT table, without UNION, ROLLUP or CUBE?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, aggregation, cube, rollup

Can someone help out with calculating a total row at the bottom of this PIVOT table please?

```
    select *, [Drug1] + [Drug2] + [Drug3] + [Drug4] + [Drug5] as [Total]
from 
        (Select [id], [drug], [Diagnosis]
            from DrugDiagnosis
        ) as ptp
        pivot 
            (count(id) 
                for drug 
                in ([Drug1], [Drug2], [Drug3], [Drug4], [Drug5]) 
            ) as PivotTable
```

I know I can do it with a UNION and have a separate query to calc the totals, but that will double the hit on the database.

I have found examples using ROLLUP and CUBE, but these are deprecated features so I don't want to use them.

Any other ideas, GROUPING SETS maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUPING SETS`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to get the totals row:

```
select isnull(diagnosis, 'Total') Diagnosis, 
  sum([Drug1]) Drug1, sum([Drug2]) Drug2, 
  sum([Drug3]) Drug3, sum([Drug4]) Drug4, 
  sum([Drug5]) Drug5,
  sum([Drug1] + [Drug2] + [Drug3] + [Drug4] + [Drug5]) as [Total]
from 
(
  Select [id], [drug], [Diagnosis]
  from DrugDiagnosis
) as ptp
pivot 
(
  count(id) 
  for drug in ([Drug1], [Drug2], [Drug3], [Drug4], [Drug5]) 
) as PivotTable
group by grouping sets((diagnosis), ());
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cff1/1)