# How do I get rollup count 'Total' in table

Tags: php, mysql, report, rollup

I have created a table in the database which displays Date, User, Value. The following is a revised design:

```
   Date    | User  | Value  
---------- | ----- | -----
```

So each user has a count of what submissions they have done matching via the date. The results are displayed from this query from the database

```
SELECT * FROM testreport
```

Please see the new design below as mentioned from the comments, I have added the row total at the end.

```
   Date    | User1 | User2 | User3 |    Value 
---------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | -----------
23-02-2017 |   2   |   5   |   9   |     16
24-02-2017 |   5   |   7   |   11  |     23   
25-02-2017 |   6   |   13  |   1   |     20
```

But what I am trying to achieve is by selecting the table and have total to show in the last row like this, how do I go about doing this:

```
   Date    | User1 | User2 | User3 |    Value 
---------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | -----------
23-02-2017 |   2   |   5   |   9   |     16
24-02-2017 |   5   |   7   |   11  |     23   
25-02-2017 |   6   |   13  |   1   |     20
Total      |   13  |   25  |   21  |     59
```

but I cannot specify the column names like [How do I calc a total row using a PIVOT table, without UNION, ROLLUP or CUBE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463092/how-do-i-calc-a-total-row-using-a-pivot-table-without-union-rollup-or-cube). Because from time time there will be extra users added to this table but I want to be able to get all the columns with totals at the end. On my site I am using PHP to display the table on the page with the code:

```
$sqlres = "SELECT * FROM testreport order by Date DESC ";
$resultsql = mysqli_query($sqlres) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($resultsql); $i++) {
    $field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($resultsql, $i);
    echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
}

// Print the data
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($resultsql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($rows as $_column) {
        echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Which displays the headers and rows as I wanted them to be and any new user I add to the 'testreport' table column it automatically adds an extra column on the page, how do I go about achieving the rollup of these columns to get total.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by insecure API, sorry i'm a newbie so how do i go about fixing my design

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API was deprecated a long time ago. See mysqli_ or, better, PDO. As for the design, one option might be `Date | user | val`

Comment: Thanks for the details on mysql_API, as for the design I have made the edit and amended my db table but I still need a total at the bottom to display above counts. Is there any further insight to this?

Comment: Amend your question accordingly. I cannot see the revised design

Comment: I have added the revised design and obiously new design is as follows

Comment: Um, you haven't revised the design. The revised table design would have only 3 columns !?!?

Comment: Hi I have made the edit Date, User, Val